# Selecting Objects in Maya using Qt and Python?

Tags: python, qt, maya

I am building a tool for people to clone existing objects in their scene and scale the new objects by it's X and Y dimensions as part of a school project. But the first step is for a person to "highlight" or select an object.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to tell the program to work with the current;y selected object. What could would I run for my program to register the current selected object?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does this need to be a QT objects? the default maya.cmds `nameField` object contains an automatic link to a scene object via it's `object` property so it's a good match for this case.

You can always get the selected object in a script with `cmds.ls()` of course

Comment: Yes, it will need to be a QT object.